# Configurable Product create/update "No data to save" with too many options

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7

I have a strange issue with Magento 2.0.7 - 2.1.0 versions in my vps. When I try to create multiple options (more than 30 variations of color and sizes), it gives me "No data to save" error while trying to save the product. If I create a product with only around 10 child products for a configurable product, it does not give me any error. Attached are the error screenshot and my server's php.ini settings. This vps has 8gb of ram and enough ssd space. Please hint me something I am missing. I tried to increase several php configuration settings `max_input_vars`, `opcache.max_accelerated_files` etc. Nothing helped. It seems something related to session. But not sure what it is.[image]

Comment: I'd be glad if any one can give me some idea to solve it

Comment: i have the same error with all product types. Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has this problem, we had an issue where the server configuration forced a trailing slash behind all URL's. This forced a redirect which resulted in a faulty request and caused this issue. When we commented the rewrite rule in the nginx settings the we could save the products.